# What to change when neural network is not classifying correctly?

Tags: algorithm, ai

I'm designing a learning algorithm for a simulation. In this simulation, there are minesweepers/tanks and also mines. Tanks are supposed to avoid collisions with mines, I'm using a neural network for teach them to avoid mines.

The inputs to my neural network are:

- Angle betweem tank and mine
- Distance between tank and mine

I'm trying to teach the network the following avoidance algorithm (pseudocode):

```
        if (angle < 10 && dist < 15){
            if mine is in clockwise direction:
                return -PI/4
            else 
                return PI/4
        }
        else{
            return 0
        }
```

This will result in the tank not changing direction, turning left or right of mine.
I have three layers in my network, 2 input neurons, 4 hidden neurons and 1 output neuron. Ive been testing my network with 300, 1000 and 42666 training examples. The best it's done is to produce only two directions for the tank, it never turns left meaning my network does not classify the -PI/4 part.

What can I tune to make it work? Do I increase training examples and iterations in the training loop, increase hidden number of neurons?

[**EDIT**]

I think I should mention that I'm using the hyperbolic function as an activation function. I added a bias to the inputs, the tanks are now doing a better job at avoiding mines, however, they still cannot turn left (network does not give negative values) hence they collide sometimes.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered.  This is basically a "debug my code for me" question which doesn't even provide the code.

Comment: I don't think so. What I'm asking is what parameters greatly affect the learning method, is it learning rate, etc. So that I can change them accordingly. This is different from sayin' "hey, my code wont compile. What should I do?"

Comment: Getting code to compile is just one type of debugging. Either way, I think the main point is that *it's hard to understand the situation based on only these details*. Is the problem 2- or 3-dimensional in space? What movement abilities do tanks have? How are you training the neural net? How do you know that the problem is with the net? Have you tested the tanks' movement code in isolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly if you have a solution on how to do this don't use a neural network they are best in problem domains where the data is prone to be noisy and complex.

That said I'll carry on assuming a neural network is the right choice.

Your training data will need examples were -pi/4 is the expected output. In terms of volume you should be able to do it easily with that much data, are you using training and validation sets? Really you should train the network on around 60-70% of the whole data and use the other 40-30% to make sure the network is getting better at generalising and not just turning into a fancy lookup table.

Another point with the data, it should be normalised ideally. Say you have two inputs distance and rotation and in one instance you had a rotation of 0.2 rads and a distance of 200 metres the distance input will have a big effect on the output and the rotation will have a negligible effect. Normalise your inputs and they have the same sway on the networks output.

Moving from the data to the network.

A neuron traditionally has input legs and a bias leg, the values put into these give an output. Without a bias leg your neurons will be limited to positive values (which you naturally don't want).

When dealing with multilayer networks the back propagation algorithm is most common for training, you need an algorithm that can adapt each layers weights to minimise training time.

In terms of training the network, learning rate, momentum, network topology and iterations are what performance hinges on. These effect the network as follows:

Learning rate is basically the rate of change of the weights, the higher it is the quicker the network reaches an equilibrium however a lower learning rate although it takes longer moves through the state space at a finer resolution making it less likely to miss the optimal solution.

Momentum keeps the networks adjustments moving in a similar direction, this is useful to prevent the network reach equilibrium in a local minima in the state space. It will essentially overshoot the suboptimal solution and if at the right value keep going to the solution. When it reaches the solution it will overshoot, come back on itself and eventually decrease to settle (much like a pendulum swinging and coming to a stop). Momentum is useful in preventing premature stops.

Iterations the longer you go the more chance you have of reaching that equilibrium point where the network is just leaping on and off the best solution it can find given the learning rate and momentum used. Too many iterations can cause the network to "overlearn" and basically become a fancy lookup table working on your input data but not working as well on data it wasn't trained on. There are methods using the validation set to decide when to stop training based on a minimum desired accuracy or the point where the accuracy on the validation set starts to decrease on average.

Network layout. You really need to experiment with this one, too many it may not settle easily, too few hidden neurons it won't solve the problem sufficiently. There are heuristics to choose a number of hidden neurons but really trial and error is the best way.

Saying all this I don't think a neural network is the best solution for this. It's generally too uncontrollable/esoteric for game ai. I've used a neural network in one project it was classifying radar returns from the ionosphere and had 34 inputs from 3 high frequency receivers (an academic project). I achieved a 99.6% accuracy of classification. This is generally what neural networks are best at, for game AI I'd stick to behaviour trees, finite state machines, fuzzy logic and GOAP.

But neural networks are fun, and you are more than welcome to give it a shot you'll definitely learn from it.